# Is there a JQuery event to determine when an element's list of children has changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hoping to find a JQuery event that will tell me when an element collection has grown or shrunk after the addition/removal of a child element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count child elements initially then use a conditional statement to check whether count changed.

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>

alert($('div').children().length);
```

Answer (score 12):

What you are looking for are the DOMNodeInserted and DOMNodeRemoved events.

For example, after you bind to a DOMNodeInserted event of a list:

```
$('ol').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
    alert('node inserted');
});
```

and then another list item is inserted:

```
$('ol').append('<li>x</li>');
```

the event is fired.

Comment: +1, and I got bored: so here's a [JS Fiddle demo of the concepts](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/f6e2T/). :)

Comment: The DOMNodeInserted event is not IE compatible. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html

Comment: I need it to be supported in IE.

Comment: Mutation events have been deprecated [for performance reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events). The replacement, [Mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers), are coming in [Firefox 14](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/04/aurora-14-is-out-whats-new-in-it/) and Chrome 18.