# jQuery - Trigger Event on .children().size() change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have searched near and far but I can't figure out how to put a listener on the size() of children elements.  What I am trying to do is:

I have a div with anywhere from 0-6+ child elements.  This number isn't defined because I am making a shopping cart.  Instead of onclick for every button that can change the number of items in the cart (i.e. add to cart btn, empty cart button, change quantity, etc...) I want to have a listener that when `$("#cart").children().size()` changes, an if statement checks if the #of different items in the cart is larger than 3. If so change the height of the div.

an example of the shopping cart layout:

```
<div id='cart'>
     <div class='item'></div>
     <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

The actual code site is at: http://www.jamesendres.com/projects/ad/throw-pillows.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm affraid div doesn't have the `change` event, so it would be impossible to listen it. On the other hand, you can create your own handler to get over this situation.

I've create a fiddle showing the proof of concept: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hjarvard/ZVYVW/5/).

The code is very simple and I think you can understand it easily. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is close to what I am trying to do.  Firstly thanks for the help.  I worded the question wrong by saying change.  Change only works with inputs, selects, radios.  What I am trying to do is place a listener on the cart div to see whenever an item is added or removed instead of having a listener on the buttons that do the adding or subtracting.  There are at least 5 different way to added or remove an item to/from the basket and I am trying to avoid having to listen for the 5+ buttons and instead only listen only for the #cart.children().size().

Comment: Unless the only way to do it is by watching for the click events.

Comment: Yeah, I understood you. Another option how to achieve this is to create custom jQuery plugin. Plugin should be added to your `#cart` item (like `$("#cart").pluginName()`) and then each time when you want to manipulate with that element you should use your plugin's methods (like `$("#cart").pluginName("add", params)` or `$("#cart").pluginName("remove", params)`). I think it sounds tricky but if you can't handle this just say and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thank you for the help, cleared things up!  I will give it a go with the plugin, although for the amount of buttons I could just use your other answer.  Either way I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for voting! This is really motivates me. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You probably want "DOMNodeInserted" event.like:

```
$('ol').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
    alert('node inserted');
});
```

See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5033719/907753

Comment: This is deprecated now.  The `bind` function is deprecated in JQuery, and the `DOMNodeInserted` event is deprecated across browsers.